# How to Add OR Condition in Laravel Sphinx query?

Tags: php, laravel, sphinx, sphinxql

I am using the `fobia/laravel-sphinx` package and want to add a condition like `city != 0 or state != 0` but the `or` condition is not working and gives tjis error:

> "Syntax error or access violation: 1064 sphinxql: syntax error,
> unexpected OR, expecting $end near 'or "

```
$query->where('state_id', '!=', 0)->orWhere('city_id', '!=', 0);
```

It uses `\Fobia\Database\SphinxConnection\Eloquent\Model`

Comment: It will depend on the version of sphinx being used. OR in where is a modern construct, older versions didn't support. Sounds like you have older searchd version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a version of sphinx/manticore server that is not supporting OR conditions, have to 'fake' using a fake attribute/expression.

Need to add a column. Want SphinxQL somewhat like

```
SELECT *, (state_id!=0)+(city_id!=0) as filter FROM index WHERE filter > 0
```

... ie will only inlcude rows, where the sum of state_id and city_id is above zero. Ie either one of them is not zero.

Alas reading the laravel-sphinx source, can't figure out how to add to the columns list. Seems needs needs adding to $query->columns. So dont know if something like

```
 $query->columns[] = "(state_id!=0)+(city_id!=0) AS filter";
 $query->where('filter', '>', 0);
```

or maybe

```
 $query->select(['*',"(state_id!=0)+(city_id!=0) AS filter"])->where('filter', '>', 0);
```

seems the there is a 'select' method in the base query builder
https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html

Answer (score 0):

you cant use OR condition in Sphinx
you can handle it with `whereNotIn` and `whereIn`

Comment: but how ? can you give example of $query->where('state_id', '!=', 0)->orWhere('city_id', '!=', 0); into whereNotIn  and whereIn converting

Comment: something like this  $query->whereNotIn ('state_id', 0);   $query->whereNotIn ('city_id', 0); @SejalGauswami

Comment: but this will return true only if both state_id field and city_id field both has value.
i need result true if any of the field either state_id or city_id has value then true

Answer (score 0):

These are the top rated real world PHP examples of **yii\sphinx\Query::orWhere** extracted from open source projects. You can rate examples to help us improve the quality of examples.
[Please Visit and see example](https://hotexamples.com/examples/yii.sphinx/Query/orWhere/php-query-orwhere-method-examples.html)

Comment: But in laravel how can i implement ?
i tried $query->where('state_id', '!=', 0)->orWhere('city_id', '!=', 0); but its not working it gives error

Comment: What error it gives. share error message here for more clarity.

Comment: "Syntax error or access violation: 1064 sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected OR, expecting $end near 'or "